# How to get map to show longitude and latitude accurately with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates

I'm using d3.js to try to map coordinates for a csv data file that contains an order id, latitude & longitude of the address the order was shipped to, and the amount that was spent on the order.  I've tried mapping them out linearly and tried using a log scale, but the plot points still seem skewed.  I was trying to get it to look like a map of the US which it slightly resembles, but the map seems warped/skewed.  I made sure that the longitude was set to the x-axis and that latitude was set for the y-axis. The radius of the circles are related to the amount spent on orders. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the scale used, but this is my first time trying to mess with d3, so any help/advice would be appreciated!

```
  var outerWidth  = 500;
  var outerHeight = 250;
  var margin = { left: -50, top: 0, right: -50, bottom: 0 };

  var xColumn = "longitude";
  var yColumn = "latitude";
  var rColumn = "total";
  var dollarPerPixel = 10;

  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var xScale = d3.scale.log().range([0, innerWidth]);
  var yScale = d3.scale.log().range([innerHeight, 0]);
  var rScale = d3.scale.sqrt();

  function render(data){

    xScale.domain( d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[xColumn]; }));
    yScale.domain( d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[yColumn]; }));
    rScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[rColumn]; })]);

    // Compute the size of the biggest circle as a function of dollarPerPixel.
    var dollarMax = rScale.domain()[1];
    var rMin = 0;
    var rMax = Math.sqrt(dollarMax / (dollarPerPixel * Math.PI));
    rScale.range([rMin, rMax]);

    var circles = g.selectAll("circle").data(data);
    circles.enter().append("circle");
    circles
      .attr("cx", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("cy", function (d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]); })
      .attr("r",  function (d){ return rScale(d[rColumn]); });
    circles.exit().remove();
  }

  function type(d){
    d.latitude   = +d.latitude;
    d.longitude  = +d.longitude;
    d.total = +d.total;
    return d;
  }

  d3.csv("data.csv", type, render);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this warped/skewed result should be expected since all map projections necessarily distort the surface in some fashion?

Comment: It's not even close to how it should look though.  I'm trying to get something like this http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToD3/examples/viewer/#/96 but only for US coordinates.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_equal-area_projection Looks like this formula produces a Lambert Cylindrical projection. If you had a map created using this projection and it lined up, you'd know for sure. Something you might try to correct for the type of map you have is a css transform skew to make your plot area smaller at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While scales may seem to be an appropriate method for plotting geographic points: don't use this approach.

You lose control over rotation of a projection and you cannot use a non cylindrical projection (only unrotated cylindrical projections can plot lat and long independently). But it also makes it very hard to align features positioned by scales with other map elements if they don't use the same approach.

Instead, D3 has a wide range of built in projections.

The projections take a [longitude,latitude] pair and return a [x,y] coordinate. Latitudes and longitudes must be in degrees, x and y are in pixels.

To create a projection you can use:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator() // or geoAlbers, geoSupportedProjection, etc.
```

To use it, just pass it a coordinate:

```
projection([long,lat]) // [x,y]
```

In your case this might look like (for the cx, cy looks similar)

```
 .attr("cx", function(d) { return projection([d.long,d.lat])[0] })
```

Now this projection is centered at 0,0 degrees by default and set up for a 960x500 pixel map. But you can modify scale, center and rotation, for example:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([-100,35]).scale(1000)
```

For a more complete run down of projection methods you should look at the documentation for d3-geo.

In your case there is a special composite projection that covers the US, d3.geoAlbersUsa, which has room for Hawaii and Alaska. But, because of its composite nature is less flexible, though you can still scale it. The default scale anticipates   960x600 pixel map (setting larger map scales spreads the map over a larger area).

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was very helpful.  I will try it later tonight and mark your answer as the correct one.